# Is it possible to combine JSTL & Sightly components on a page in AEM6?

Tags: jstl, aem, sightly

I have currently only developed on CQ5 and I'm starting with AEM6 was wondering if you can combine JSTL written components with Sightly written components on a page.

We are considering to upgrade, but we don't want to rebuild all components immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use components that are written in sightly on the same page as components that are written in jsp. You can have a component that has a sightly file that includes a jsp file, or a jsp file that includes a sightly file. You cannot have a single file that uses both jsp and sightly.